# laptop touchpad software

Tags: laptop, touchpad

In laptop store i saw a laptop, which provides user to make additional functions by using touchpad.
For example if you move two fingers seperately it makes zoom in, if you move your finger up and down, it makes reload.

I have forgotten the software name. Do you know its name?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the software is very closely related to the hardware, so the program is most likely made by touchpad manufacturer.

For example my touchpad made by Synaptics can provide additional features using Synaptics' [Scrybe](http://www.uscrybe.com/) software. So even though my touchpad predates multitouch, I can use two finger zoom, three finger tap and swipe, symbol recognition and so on.

Answer (score 4):

It's called multi-touch, and it's a feature that has to be supported in hardware, not just software.